# Execute tasks one after the other by means of a cronjob

Tags: cron

I have three tasks/scripts to be executed one after the other by means of a cron-job. The first task should be executed every third minute of the hour. When the first task is completed, the second task should be executed and when the second finishes, the third should execute.

Each of these task are written in a simple PHP file which I can execute by means of a command line.

Please help me

Comment: Create a single cron job that calls the three commands in order.

Comment: I have edited your question to the best of my abilities. Please indicate if this still accurately describes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a small wrapper-script that execurtes the jobs one by one and add (only) this wrapper-script to cron.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/first_job.sh
/path/to/second_job.sh
/path/to/third_job.sh
```

And here an example that will execute the next job only if the previous job had exit status 0 (what means "success"):

```
#!/bin/bash
if /path/to/first_job.sh ; then
  if /path/to/second_job.sh ; then
    /path/to/third_job.sh
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Is there any way that whenever 1st cron got done after 3 minutes of it .. 2nd cron will call?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by @7thson and the comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

/path/to/first_job.sh
sleep 180
/path/to/second_job.sh
sleep 180
/path/to/third_job.sh
```

`sleep ${seconds}` waits for three (3) minutes before executing the next script.
`set -e` causes the script to exit if any of the jobs fail, so the following scripts will not be executed if one of them fails (i.e. causes an exit code other than 0).